# How to train a ssd-mobilenet from scratch

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, mobilenet

How can I retrain a ssd-mobilenet-v2 from the tensorflow object detection model zoo without transfer learning. I mean every weight and not just the last layer.

Do I have to build the network architecture and the script for training or can I make some minor change to the .config file or the train.py script specified in the docs on training a custom object detector.

Will this approach improve/worsen the network accuracy/loss?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

First, by default all parameters are being retrained, unless you defined otherwise in the pipeline.config.

There's a file named **pipeline.config**, which you use to control your training process.
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config

In the config file you can define whether you want to load the model parameters from a checkpoint or not.
There are a several actions you can choose:
 1. load parameters for the backbone (i.e. your mobilenet feature extractor)
 2. load parameters for the prediction and regressions heads.
 3. don't load parameters (usually you won't prefer this one - will take longer to train and converge)

To be more specific, you should focus the following nodes in the pipline.config:

1. fine_tune_checkpoint - checkpoint for the original model you want to use to do transfer learning.
2. fine_tune_checkpoint_type - define whether the checkpoint is **classification**/**detection**
3. load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars - if **True** - then the parameters from the fine_tune_checkpoint will be loaded before the start of the training.
4. freeze_variables - in case you don't want to retrain all the parameters you can define which variables to freeze.
   ( see full documentation of these in their proto file **object_detection/protos/train.proto)** - https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/train.proto)

Example:

```
153   fine_tune_checkpoint: "<PATH-TO-DOWNLOADED-CKPT>/model.ckpt"
154   fine_tune_checkpoint_type: detection
155   load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: true
```

All parameters will be loaded and retrained.